# Six throws, only two distinct numbers: coincidence?

Tags: probability, dice

My daughter threw a die (D6) six times and got: 6,2,2,6,2,6.

This got us wondering whether having only two distinct numbers come up in six throws was very unlikely or would happen fairly often. How would we go about working out the answer to that question? (short of doing it lots of times and counting!)

Comment: Real dice are different that abstract dice.

Comment: Right, but presumably not in a way that I can quantify or determine, so the 'theoretical' answer is still the best I can do, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe... you can experiment a number of trials and compare to see if the expected evolution of the trials follow the law of large numbers, If not you can assume some "weight" in the dice. And, but Im not sure, you can model the happenings trough some bayesian analysis.

Comment: See [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/data/1050262.pdf) or [here](http://personal.vu.nl/a.f.de.vos/primer/primer.pdf), maybe interesting.

Comment: nice, thanks :)

Comment: @Masacroso I think it's fairly safe to say that real dice are more or less fair. You are overcomplicating this answer by quite a margin, I think. The question, as far as I see it, is simply "what is the probability of rolling only two numbers when rolling a 6 sided die six times?" and it has a simple solution that does not even include experimenting.

Comment: But I would be interested on this "overcomplicating", so other people can be interested too. I dont understand the reason to limit answers @5xum.

Comment: @Masacroso Point taken. If OP finds your answer useful, then I guess it's a good answer. Still I feel like you answered a much more complicated answer (which may confuze some people).

Comment: @Masacroso Citation, please, for your implicit claim that real dice are not very well approximated by independent uniform random variables.

Comment: [Bill Nye explains why this happens when the kids deal with coin tosses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUcZTcSY7Zo) It's worth a watch with your daughter.

Comment: The first time I had three 10-sided dice, I rolled them together and got 0, 0, 0. My dad didn't believe me when I told him. :-)

Comment: A closely related problem is [the Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: In general, "is this interesting thing that just happened unlikely?" is a bit awkward question: unlikely things do occur with a small probability but there may be plenty of possible interesting unlikely things, so the probability that _something_ interesting and unlikely happens is actually much larger than some might expect. Of course there's nothing wrong with asking such questions if you know what you're asking.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are a total of $6^6$ possible outcomes of rolling a die six times. How many of those contain exactly $2$ distinct numbers?

Well, there are ${6\choose 2} = 15$ different pairs of  numbers from $1$ to $6$, and for each pair of numbers, there are $2^6$ rolls of dice that contain only those two numbers. However, two of those contain only one of the numbers, so $2^6- 2$ is the number of rolls of two numbers that contains both of those numbers.

All together, this means there are $15\cdot (2^6-2)$ good outcomes out of $6^6$, so the probability of this occuring is $$\frac{15(2^6-2)}{6^6} \approx 1.99331\%$$
so what happened is something that happens rougly every once in $50$ tries. Rare, but not much rarer than rolling a double six with two dice, for example.

Comment: +1 for the comparison with a familiar probability at the end.

Comment: Here's an embarrassing question - what is (6 2). Six over two in parentheses? You don't have to explain it. I can look it up if I know what it is. :-)

Comment: @Mayo http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: thx peaceoutside.

Answer (score 10):

**Here is an alternative solution to the (very good) answer already given here:**

The number of ways that you can choose $2$ out of $6$ values is $\dbinom{6}{2}=15$.

Given $2$ values A and B, the number of combinations that you can get in $6$ rolls is:

- Value A appearing $1$ time  and value B appearing $5$ times: $\dbinom{6}{1}=6$
- Value A appearing $2$ times and value B appearing $4$ times: $\dbinom{6}{2}=15$
- Value A appearing $3$ times and value B appearing $3$ times: $\dbinom{6}{3}=20$
- Value A appearing $4$ times and value B appearing $2$ times: $\dbinom{6}{4}=15$
- Value A appearing $5$ times and value B appearing $1$ time : $\dbinom{6}{5}=6$

So you can get $6+15+20+15+6=62$ combinations containing A and B.

And you can get $15\cdot62=930$ combinations containing any $2$ out of $6$ values.

The total number of combinations that you can get in $6$ rolls is simply $6^6=46656$.

Therefore, the probability of having exactly $2$ values in $6$ rolls is $\dfrac{930}{46656}\approx0.0199$.

Comment: Just a note: the $62$ calculated here through sumation is precisely the $2^6 - 2$ calculated in my answer. This is due to the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^6{6\choose i} = 2^6$.

Comment: @5xum: I agree (except for the fact that you need to change `i=1` to `i=0` in the equation above). I just figured it might help if I showed OP another way for calculating that value...

Comment: Of course, $i$ must be set to $0$. I fully agree it is useful to show the OP another way, I just added a clarification so he wouldn't think $62$ is somehow magical in that it appears where you need it:P

Comment: @5xum Well, it is interesting that the answers keep on using $2^6$, 62, and other combination of 2 and 6 - the same numbers the OP kept on rolling.

Comment: @Ypnypn: It's also worth noting that so far I have asked $62$ questions on this website. In addition, I have answered $216$ questions, and in my last ($216$th) answer on a probability question, the size of the sample-space was $216$ (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/995427/131263)... Nevertheless, it is generally just a matter of chance. OP could have just as well asked about $1$ and $5$ (for example).