# discrete structures dice probability

Tags: probability

The experiment consists of rolling 3 ordinary, presumably fair, 6-sided dice, one red, one, white, and one black. Give your answers to the nearest integer.

What is the probability that the sum of the numbers on the red and white dice is less than the number on the black die?

Can i consider this problem as what is the probability that the sum of the numbers on the first two dices is less than 6 since the range of the last dice is [1,6]? or sum up the result of less than 3,4,5,6?

Therefore, we have

```
10/36
```

by the table

```
+ 1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Then it asks me to output the result as,

```
X/1000
```

which by conversion,

```
10/36 = 278/1000
```

However, the system doesn't accept this answer. Anything goes wrong? Thanks.

Comment: We need to consider (probably separately) the various possibilities for the black die.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so it would be less than 6,less than 5, less than 4,and less than 3?

Comment: Yes. For example Black shows $3$ and others have sum $\lt 3$ with probability $(1/6)(1/36)$. Black shows $4$ and others have sum $\lt 4$ with probability $(1/6)(3/36)$. Two more cases.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks Andre. Go alone with this logic we have Black shows 5 and others have sum<5 with probability (1/6)(6/36), Black shows 6 and others have sum<6 with probability (1/6)(10/36). The total would be (1/6)(1/36)+(1/6)(3/36)+(1/6)(6/36)+(1/6)(10/36)=(1/6)(20/36)=(5/54)?

Comment: Yes, so we add up, get $20/216$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks! got it

Comment: You are welcome. There is useful general structure here, we could solve the problem for $n$-sided dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of combinations is $6^3=216$.

For black $=3$, there is $1$ option for the sum of the other two dice to be smaller:

- $(1,1)$

For black $=4$, there are $2$ additional options (hence $3$ options altogether):

- $(1,2)$
- $(2,1)$

For black $=5$, there are $3$ additional options (hence $6$ options altogether):

- $(1,3)$
- $(2,2)$
- $(3,1)$

For black $=6$, there are $4$ additional options (hence $10$ options altogether):

- $(1,4)$
- $(2,3)$
- $(3,2)$
- $(4,1)$

Altogether, there are $1+3+6+10=20$ such cases, hence the probability is $\dfrac{20}{216}$.