# Probability of throwing exactly $V$ distinct sides on $N$ sided dice by $K$ rolls

Tags: probability, dice

I'm struggling with finding a non-recursive formula for calculating the following probability:

Probability of throwing exactly $V$ distinct sides (numbers) on $N$ sided dice by $K$ rolls

Example for a normal dice where number of sides $N=6$, rolls $K=6$ and required distinct sides $V=2$ can be found here: [Six throws, only two distinct numbers: coincidence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994728/six-throws-only-two-distinct-numbers-coincidence)

The formula in the example is not general and only solution I can find is recursive one which I cannot use.

Comment: It would surprise me if the fact that you can only find recursive solutions is coincidental. I suspect there is no closed-form general solution for this.

Comment: I hope it's just because I'm quite lame at closed formulas rather than  the closed formula doesn't exist :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be using Stirling numbers of the second kind:

$$\frac{1}{N^K} \times {N\choose V} \times V! \times {K\brace V}.$$

These probabilities sum to one (${K\brace 0} = 0$ when $K\ge 1$):

$$\frac{1}{N^K} \sum_{V=0}^N ·{N\choose V} V! 
K! [z^K] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^V}{V!}
\\ = \frac{1}{N^K} K! [z^K] \sum_{V=0}^N ·{N\choose V} V! 
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^V}{V!}
\\ = \frac{1}{N^K} K! [z^K] \sum_{V=0}^N ·{N\choose V} 
(\exp(z)-1)^V = \frac{1}{N^K} K! [z^K] \exp(Nz) 
=  \frac{1}{N^K} N^K = 1.$$

Comment: Sir, thank you! It works!
For anyone wanting R code:
`pform <- function(K, N, V)  ( 1/N**K ) * choose(N, V) * factorial(V) * as.numeric( Stirling2(K, V) )`